# Leaflet Map Rendering

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

My map didn't open completely, can anyone help me solve it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x61n.png)

I tried to recreate the code and install it again, I tried to get the code from the website itself and it didn't work,I'm using React and TailwindCSS,someone who can help me please ?

Comment: It's difficult to see the problem without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0):

In the file where you created your map component, you must import the following styles.

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

and where you add the Tailwind directives to your CSS you must create the style for the height and width of the map.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.leaflet-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```